# Does the access token received from Google's NodeJs Auth Lib needs checking for validity?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-api-nodejs-client

Is it safe to assume that the OAuth 2 credentials (access and refresh tokens) received from [google-auth-library-nodejs](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/)'s method `getToken` are:

1. valid;
2. valid for the intended user;
3. valid for the current app.

Or should I perform the validation after getting the credentials, for example using the `tokeninfo` endpoint of the `googleapis.com/oauth2` url?